# What is the abstract formalization behind the common characteristic shortcut?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory

When people work with automomous ODE, or sometimes PDE, they often defer to the characteristic equation in operator form to find the characteristic values. It's an interesting heuristic method, but formalizing it is often beyond the scope of an introductory course on ODE.

I'll give you an example: let's say you're postulated an ODE $y'' -2y' + y = 0,$ then someone might represent this in operator form as $(D^2 -2D + 1)[y] =0,$ where $D = \frac{d}{dx}$ and then find the roots of $D^2 - 2D + 1$ to find the eigenvalues.

But, as it turns out, the differential operator is [unbounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator), and according to that article, unbounded operators don't (often) form an algebra.

So, what is the algebra or mathematical magic that allows one to combine various powers of $D$ into a new operator?

Answer (score 0):

Differential operators do form an algebra: they take the space of $C^\infty$ functions into itself (and that's all you need for differential equations where all terms are $C^\infty$).

Comment: Many theorems in PDE and ODE though assume $y'$ is continuous, such as the fundamental theorem of linear systems or the Banach contraction theorem. How is this discrepancy reconciled? It happens to be the case exponentials are smooth, but you don't know that before the equation is solved. Also, can you provide a reference on the algebra itself? Because for instance, suspect multiplication is not just regular multiplication on a differential algebra, but rather represents compositing multiple operators, explaining powers.